# No fold found with python code, mac and debian

Tags: folding, python

I'm trying to get vim to do code folding with my python code and I could really use your help with the last bit here.

I have this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set number
"set tabstop=2
"set expandtab
"set sw=2
set nowrap
syntax on
set linebreak
set textwidth=80
set background=dark

" Enable folding
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99
filetype plugin indent on

" Enable folding with the spacebar
nnoremap <space> za
```

I've been testing with the following file

```
from filelock import FileLock
import yaml

def main() -> int:
    """
    main control loop
    """
    #Read config file
    read_config()
    #Lock
```

I've tried this file with double spaces, four spaces, single tabs, so far nothing has worked. Everything results in "E490 fold not found".

I've tried running `set foldmethod=indent` after loading the file, I've confirmed that `:set syntax` returns `syntax=python`, I've tried a ruby file and code folding works there so it appears to be something about the python I've crafted that it doesn't like.
I've tried without the python type hinting (`-> int`), no change.

I tried installing vim from brew, confirmed I'm using vim from the new path, no change.

I've tried replicating this on a Debian Buster vm so I don't think it's mac specific.

I even tried putting an 'end' which isn't syntactically correct at the end of the function definition just as an experiment, that didn't work either.

This is the output of `vim --version`

```
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-2900
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       -tcl
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
-balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              +perl              +title
-clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +wildmenu
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -X11
-dnd               +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lm -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework AppKit -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.4 -mmacosx-version-min=11.3 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -L/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin -lpython3.9 -framework CoreFoundation -lruby.3.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.1/lib
```

Any ideas how else to poke at or fix this? It's probably something small and silly so Ill apologize now, I just can't see it at the moment.. Thanks in advance!

References:

- https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Folding
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441014/macvim-can-not-fold-code-e490-no-fold-found
- https://old.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/49c882/vim_intended_folding_e490_no_fold_found/

Update1: Added `filetype plugin indent on` to vimrc, recommended in comments.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might find [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) somewhat helpful, along with various links in `:help 'foldmethod'`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** You also need to add the following line to your vimrc:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

See [`:h :filetype-plugin-on`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype-plugin-on) and [`:h :filetype-indent-on`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype-indent-on) this command enable the filetype detection and the loading of the indent scripts which are necessary to have working folding.

---

You can't set `foldmethod` directly from the vimrc, see [`:h 'fdm'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fdm%27):

```
'foldmethod' 'fdm'  string (default: "manual")
            local to window
```

The key words here are `local to window`: Setting the fold method in your vimrc will not affect the other splits you open.

You need to create a ftplugin [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin) for python and put the setting in it. Create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` and put your `set foldmethod=indent` there.

Comment: Btw I'm 100% sure that we have at least one duplicate of this question but I can't find it

Comment: That didn't work for me, putting 'set foldmethod=indent' as the contents of ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim. I mentioned in my post but I also tried 'set foldmethod=indent' in vim *after* loading the file, I don't think this is a vimrc problem but I could be mistaken. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Ah right @JeffWelling you forgot to put `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc that's why it doesn't work I think

Comment: Hm, I added `filetype plugin indent on` right below `set foldlevel=99` but that doesn't seem to have done it either, I appreciate your help though @statox! I also tried doing 'set foldmethod=indent' after loading the file, to your point about it being local to the window, no change. This was with ftplugin/python.vim in place and rm'd, no change.

Comment: Now that's weird... I don't have an idea of what else could be wrong. Since it doesn't work only for python files maybe there is something with the built-in python ftplugin but since you use `indent` I don't see how that would play.

Comment: If you have the time, and I know this is a bit of an ask but, could I ask you to see if it works for you? I'll try cloning some python projects to see if it's the python I've crafted or just all python code.

Comment: Firstly, can you confirm where your cursor is when you are trying to fold?  Secondly, just to check nothing is being overriden, what is the output of `:filetype` and `:verbose set foldmethod`?

Comment: Are you sure `set fdm=indent` couldn't be set from .vimrc? I have it there it works for me for all filetypes that do not override fdm.

Answer (score 0):

With the settings you have it should work.

Press `zM` to close all folds. Note if you press `za` on `def main` it would not toggle the fold -- it doesn't exist on that line. Put your cursor on indented line and press `za` there

[image]

[image]
PS

Make sure you have matching `shiftwidth` to your actual indent.